# Elasticsearch delete after field time

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index containing data with the field "expirationDate" which is a datetime object. I want to set these documents to automatically delete after that time has passed? Is there anyway to do this, or anyway I can cron this within elasticsearch to automatically run once an hour?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable TTL for your index (see [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html#_enabled_2)) and then add `_ttl` field to documents containing number of milliseconds till `expirationDate`.

Of course, you need to remember to update `_ttl` field whenever `expirationDate` changes.

---

The only way (I can think of) to set the document to expire on specific time is definitely hacky. You could configure [`_timestamp`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) path to point to your `expirationDate` field and set `_ttl` to 1 millisecond. It could work, but for me it sounds a little bit like a 'feature abuse'.

Comment: That seems to be most of the way there. It seems that at index time I have to specify how long until the document expires. Is there anyway I can just say expired at '2014-06-11T10:55' or something similar?

Comment: @user2694306 I updated my answer with the only solution I could have come up with.